# Как подключить библиотеку AForge.NET в PascalABC.NET?

Tags: pascalabc.net, aforge

Я хочу попробовать сделать фото с камеры моего компьютера, для этого я установил библиотеку AForge.NET, в установщике ничего не изменял, всё по умолчанию. Как подключить её к программе на PascalABC.NET, чтобы я мог её там использовать?
Я пытался как обычно, сделать `{$reference 'AForge.dll'}`, но пишет "Сборка 'AForge.dll' не найдена".

P.S.
Тупой вопрос)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каком каталоге лежит ваша библиотека? Попробуйте переместить еë в каталог с вашей программой:

```
|
+-AForge
| |
| +- файлы библиотеки... 
|
+- файлы вашей программы...
```

{$reference 'AForge/AForge.dll'}

Comment: AForge лежит в C:\Program Files (x86)\AForge.NET\Framework
Спасибо, попробую

Comment: можно поискать AForge.dll в поиске windows. .NET библиотеки любят ставиться в GAC (папка %windir%\assembly)

Comment: Нашёл AForge.dll

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое!